# Add multiple values to localStorage and then retrieve a random one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a system where the user inputs multiple values at separate times and then can click a button that tells them one of their inputs (at random). This is what I have so far:

(Note: for some odd reason this code snippet is not functioning properly here (at least not on my side) but it is working just fine in JS Bin and even my own Notepad++)

```js
function store(){
  var toStore = document.getElementById("itemInputBox");
  localStorage.setItem("itemInputBox", toStore.value);
}

function get(){
  var toGet = localStorage.getItem("itemInputBox");
  document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = toGet;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="itemForm">
    <input type="text" id="itemInputBox" autocomplete="off" onmouseout="store()"><br><br>
    <button id="getStoredValue" onclick="get()" type="button" style="cursor:pointer;">Get Input Value</button>
  </form>
  
  <div id="outputArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I am fairly new to coding (have been doing it for only a year or so) and I am also new to localStorage, I need some guidance for this. Thanks to whoever responds!

Comment: the reason why localstorage doesn't work in the snippet is in the console: "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Arrays in Javascript to store multiple values in the localStorage. When storing the values, they should be in JSON format. Also, when retrieving the values you have to pass that JSON string to `JSON.parse(array) and then retrieve the values.

To get a random value from that array, you can use Math functions in JavaScript. Please check the example below. It won't work in the StackOverflow code snippets section because it restricts the LocalStorage functions but you can check it locally.

```js
function store(){
var toStore = document.getElementById("itemInputBox");
var valuesJSON = get();
if (valuesJSON == null){
    createLocalStorageKey();
}
var values = JSON.parse(get());
values.items.push(toStore.value);
localStorage.setItem("itemInputBox", JSON.stringify(values));

}

function createLocalStorageKey(){
localStorage.setItem("itemInputBox", JSON.stringify({items:[]}));
}

function get(){
var toGet = localStorage.getItem("itemInputBox");
return toGet;
}

function parseValueToHTML(){
var valuesJSON = get();
if (valuesJSON == null){
    createLocalStorageKey();
}
var values = JSON.parse(get());
document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = values.items[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.items.length)];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="itemForm">
  <input type="text" id="itemInputBox" autocomplete="off"><br><br>
  <button onclick="store()" type="button">Store Value</button>
  <button id="getStoredValue" onclick="parseValueToHTML()" type="button" style="cursor:pointer;">Get Input Value</button>
  </form>

  <div id="outputArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like this last one... and I thank you all for answering, but, none seemed to work. The first one did not give a place where I could .innerHTML the random input, and although the second one had a place, it was faulty. Can you please make edits so that it actually puts a random input into the div? I have looked everywhere and couldn't find the desired answer. This is part of a larger project, and it also gives me more knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the code. Please approve the answer if it helped :)

Comment: On your updated version it is giving me a random number. To clarify, this is what I am asking:  I want a place where the user can input a value (a word), then it is added to localStorage. Then the user can input another, which is added to the storage and so on. Then I want a button that grabs a random value (that the user inputted) from the storage and displays it in the div element.

Comment: Updated the code. Now it will store values with "store value" but and retrieves a random value by "Get Input value" button

Comment: I just made an edit to your code. It wasn't working because of one small thing- the 'Store Value' button you made did not have 'type="button"' which for some reason because it is in a form, the processor did not accept. I made the same mistake when writing the code of my original question, so I was able to find the mistake in your updated code. Anyways... after I made the edit, it is just what I was looking for. Thanks for your help, I will study this, and take in the information to add it to my arsenal of knowledge. Thank you again, and I will approve this after you approve my edits. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to store your values
Before you add a new value you'll have to retrieve the array from local storage
Add the new value to the array and replace the previous array in local storage with the updated one
Use JSON to serialize the data to store it in local storage
If there is no data in local storage create an array with the value

For the get functionality, after you retrieve the array you can generate a random number from 0 to the length of the array-1 to choose a value by index.

Answer (score 0):

my way...

```js
const itemForm    = document.forms['item-form']
  ,   getAllItems = _ =>
        {
        let r = localStorage.getItem('itemInputBox')
        return  !r ? [] : JSON.parse(r)
        }
  ,   setAllItems = arr =>
        {
        localStorage.setItem('itemInputBox',JSON.stringify(arr))
        }
  ;
itemForm.setValueStored.onclick=()=>
  {
  let val = itemForm.itemInputBox.value.trim()
  if (val)
    {
    let store = getAllItems()
    if (!store.include(val))
      {
      store.push(val)
      setAllItems(store)
      }
    }
  itemForm.itemInputBox.value = ''
  }
itemForm.getStoredValue.onclick=()=>
  {
  let store = getAllItems()
  itemForm.itemInputBox.value = (!store.length) ? '' : store[Math.floor(Math.random() *store.length)]
  }
```

```html
<form name="item-form">
  <input type="text" name="itemInputBox" autocomplete="off">
  <br><br>
  <button name="setValueStored" type="button">Set value in store</button>
  <button name="getStoredValue" type="button">Get random input value from store</button>
</form>
```